# ExtJs text field - Select the entered value

Tags: select, extjs, textfield

Extjs text field:

How can we select the value in extjs text field using mouse or keys (shift + left arrrow)?

i cannot achive this by default api's. Is this a bug in extjs text field?

Comment: what version of extjs are you using, i'm using extjs 4 and this works

Comment: well it works in extjs 3.4 as well, see example http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/5rn8C/185/ , but maybe you have something that overrides this behaviour, or your shift is broken :)

Comment: Ok thanks.. i will check out my code